# Finding the Maximum Likelihood Estimate in R

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, reliability

How do I estimate the parameters through MLE for a Likelihood function like. Note that the function has 2 multiply signs and there is a integration term in the second one.[image]

Comment: What is f and s denote?

Comment: For this question to be answerable in anything other than complete (and useless) generality, the post needs to be edited to explain the notation, including precisely what $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\theta$, $f$, $S_0$, $n$, $N$, $T_0$, $U_0$, and $G$ represent.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get detailed solution advice, it would help if you provided the explicit form of everything in your likelihood function.

That said, it seems likely that this will require numerical nonlinear optimization to solve.  You're likely going to have to be able to numerically integrate the integral as part of that process.  If you can compute derivatives of the likelihood function with respect to at least one, and preferably both parameters, that will help improve the speed and robustness of the solution, but it should be possible to perform the optimization without computing the derivatives, such as by finite differences. If the likelihood function is not everywhere smooth with respect to the parameters being estimated, that will represent another challenge.

Are there constraints on the parameters being estimated, such as nonnegativity or anything else? If so, they should be incorporated into the nonlinear optimization problem formulation, and may affect the choice of algorithm/software used to numerically solve the problem.

As a practical matter, if the likelihood function is not concave (which corresponds to the problem being "convex" due to its equivalence to minimizing the negative of the likelihood function, which would be convex), you have to worry about the possibility of multiple local maxima, only one of which maybe the global maximum. In such case, the starting value (guess) used in the numerical nonlinear optimization for the parameters being estimated may be crucial,and you may need to try solving with several different starting values.

I do not presume that using R will the best way of performing the numerical nonlinear optimization, and i can say it almost surely will not be. The best numerical nonlinear optimization software is not in R, although there might be a way of calling certain nonlinear optimizers from R.